# Running zeppelin with spark 2.2 in docker

Tags: apache-spark, docker, docker-compose, apache-zeppelin

How to run Zeppelin with Spark 2.2 in docker?

if I started zeppelin in docker, It started with spark 2.1.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.7.3
```

I want to use 2.2

I tried this config, it started on windows laptop, but get error, when I run command spark in Zeppeling Notebook

```
    master:
  image: gettyimages/spark
  command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master -h master
  hostname: master
  environment:
    MASTER: spark://master:7077
    SPARK_CONF_DIR: /conf
    SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS: localhost
  expose:
    - 7001
    - 7002
    - 7003
    - 7004
    - 7005
    - 7006
    - 7077
    - 6066
  ports:
    - 4040:4040
    - 6066:6066
    - 7077:7077
    - 8080:8080
  volumes:
    - ./conf/master:/conf
    - ./data:/tmp/data


zeppelin:
  image: apache/zeppelin:0.7.3
  environment:
    ZEPPELIN_PORT: 8090
    ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS: >-
      -Dspark.driver.memory=1g
      -Dspark.executor.memory=2g
    MASTER: local[*]
    SPARK_MASTER: spark://master:7077
    SPARK_HOME: master
  ports:
    - 8090:8090
  volumes:
    - ./data:/usr/zeppelin/data
    - ./notebooks:/usr/zeppelin/notebook
```

but I get error

```
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: /zeppelin/bin/interpreter.sh: line 211: master/bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
```

Comment: First of all, try to remove all volumes from config and run it again. It may help

Comment: I am fairly certain the last two lines of your `docker-compose.yml` are goofy. Which one is it going to be? Local Spark, or remote Spark cluster. The one line says this, the other that. Apart from that, that zeppelin container only supports local-mode. You have to give it another Spark home, in order to use a remote spark cluster, see [its manual](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to use an existing image, you need to find one that was built using Spark 2. For instance, the following is using spark 2.2, to start using it run the following command

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 dylanmei/zeppelin
```

Alternativelly you can build your own image saving the content of the link bellow in a Dockerfile

https://hub.docker.com/r/dylanmei/zeppelin/~/dockerfile/

Do your changes and then build your image using

```
docker build -t myZeppelinSparkImage .
```